# Avoid scrolling in page

Tags: html

I have a webpage that uses some hidden textarea fields - for storing some javascript information (This is passed on to the server for processing).

However the only displayed form is a small form at the top - and the page has a scroller because of the hidden textareas. Is there any way - I can remove that scroller ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `display: none`, your textarea fields should not take any space.

Alternatively, use a script element as template container. Search for "javascript templates".

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal `display:none` != `display:hidden` . This looks like a good solution

Answer (score -1):

Give your body to `style='overflow-y:hidden'`

Comment: This will likely disrupt any page design. P.S. I didn't downvote

Comment: ok you can give style="display:none" to hidden textareas this will work